# Text not being set in inflated view's TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that inflates over an activity:

```
class NeedMoreTimeScreen @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    fun inflate(context: Context) {

        LayoutInflater
            .from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.screen_more_time, this, true)

        val inflatedView = LayoutInflater
            .from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.screen_more_time, this, true)

        inflatedView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        val countDownTextView = inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.countDownText)

        countDownTextView.text = "text I want to appear"
    }
}
```

.xml for the custom view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/holder"
            android:layout_width="768px"
            android:layout_height="840px"
            android:background="@color/main_background">

        <TextView
                android:text="10s"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ScreenTitle"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="160px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/countDownText"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The text appears in the TextView when I give it text in its .xml, but setting it programmatically does not appear to be executed. Why?

Comment: take a closer look at duplicate inflation and don't forget to call `inflate()` method

Comment: Need to call `invalidate()` method after setting the text.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The view is definitely inflating, the text just isn't appearing. invalidate() sounds like what I'm looking for, but when should I call it? Calling it on the inflated view and the text view before and after I attempt to set them doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
public class NeedMoreTimeScreen : RelativeLayout
{
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    {
        init();
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    {
        init();
    }
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        init();
    }

    private fun init()
    {
        // apply your inflation code here

        val layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_more_time, this, true)

        countDownTextView.text = "text I want to appear"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this had no effect.

Comment: There is only the code above. I just called it inflate() instead of init()

Comment: Sorry, no change :/

Comment: now it is not possible, i think you are making somewhere mistake, i am using the same code for custom view